# How get a ScrollBar to work on Only Left Frame Using Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to get the ScrollBar to apply only to the LeftFrame.
When I use the Canvas setup the ScrollBar applies to the whole window.

Is there better way to setup a selectable long-list table?
Should I be using a listbox instead?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")
# root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def printname(event, i):
    print ("my name is", i)
    namelabel.configure(text="test" + str(i))

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
leftFrame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff", width=700, height=500)

vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
vsb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((1,1), window=leftFrame, anchor="ne")

rightFrame = tk.Frame(root, background="#ffffff", width=300)
# vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
# canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
# vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((1,2), window=rightFrame, anchor="nw")

# rightFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=400)
# rightFrame.pack()

leftFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

textlabel = tk.Label(leftFrame, text="Player List")
textlabel.grid(row=0)
for i in range(50):
    if (i % 2):
        w = tk.Text(leftFrame, height=1, fg="white", bg="black")
    else:
        w = tk.Text(leftFrame, height=1, fg="black", bg="white")
    w.insert(1.0, "test" + str(i))
    w.configure(relief="flat")
    w.configure(state="disabled")
    w.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, a=i: printname(event, a))
    w.grid(row=7+i)

namelabel = tk.Label(rightFrame, text="Test", fg="white", bg="black")
namelabel.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: with `Listbox` code would be simpler and shorter.

Comment: if you want to scroll only `leftFrame` then don't put `rightFrame` on `Canvas`. `Scrollbar` scrolls `Canvas` - if you have `rightFrame` (and any other elements) on canvas then it will scroll it too.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you don't want something to scroll, don't put it in the canvas. Scrolling a canvas means every item added to the canvas will scroll. There's no way to avoid that. You can't scroll half of a widget.

> Is there better way to setup a selectable long-list table?

Probably, though it depends on the data you're wanting to show. If it's a list of short strings, a `Listbox` is probably a better choice. If it's blocks of text, a single text widget with some tags and custom bindings might be better than multiple widgets.